# Как получить Имя перечисления в вычисляемом поле СКД?

Tags: 1с

Есть *Перечисление*:

```
Имя | Синоним
—————————————
М   | мужской
Ж   | женский
```

Как в СКД вывести в отчёт не *Синоним*, а *Имя* перечисления?

(Перечисление просто для примера, в реальной задаче оно содержит около 50 элементов).

Comment: @mikhail взгляните, пожалуйста, на мой новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727419/1С-СКД-Повторение-шапки-отчета-на-каждой-странице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращайте через функцию общего модуля следующую конструкцию (<Значение> - это значение вашего перечисления, которое вы подаёте в функцию):

```
МетаданныеПеречисления = <Значение>.Метаданные();
ИндексЗначения = Перечисления[МетаданныеПеречисления.Имя].Индекс(<Значение>);

ИмяЗначения = МетаданныеПеречисления.ЗначенияПеречисления[ИндексЗначения].Имя;
```

Comment: По идее это правильный ответ, но он не работает у меня. Почему такая ерунда получается: в вычисляемом поле указано `полКратко( полЖертвы )`  в итоге в функцию приходит к примеру `Перечисления.Пол.женский`, но `полЖертвы.Метаданные().Имя` равно `Пол `. ПолноеИмя равно `Перечисления.Пол`

Comment: Исправил код, конструкция получилась чуть сложнее :) но точно работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое