# 1С СКД. Повторение шапки отчета на каждой странице

Tags: 1с

Как вывести шапку отчёта на каждой странице средствами СКД? То есть не формируя отчёт программно. О программных решениях есть достаточно информации, но хочется знать как это сделать самим компоновщиком.

Comment: @Mikhail Sibirev, приглашаю Вас :-)

Comment: Никак :) Хотя можете покопать в сторону произвольного макета, вот, в частности, есть статьи, где рассказано, как сделать свой заголовок отчета: 
http://www.softmaker.kz/skd/kak-v-skd-vyvesti-zagolovok-otcheta.html
http://1cskd.ru/2010/11/proizvolnyj-zagolovok/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечал на подобный вопрос на [Инфостарте](https://forum.infostart.ru/forum9/topic175854/), настройки компоновщика это не позволяют.

В модуле отчета, процедура ПриКомпоновкеРезультата

Если известна высота шапки

```
Процедура ПриКомпоновкеРезультата(ДокументРезультат, ДанныеРасшифровки, СтандартнаяОбработка)

// если высота шапки три строки
    ДокументРезультат.ПовторятьПриПечатиСтроки = ДокументРезультат.Область(1,, 3); 

КонецПроцедуры
```

Если высота шапки неизвестна, но шапка автоматически фиксируется при компоновке, то в этом случае можно использовать свойство ФиксацияСверху табличного документа.

```
Процедура ПриКомпоновкеРезультата(ДокументРезультат, ДанныеРасшифровки, СтандартнаяОбработка)

    СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;

    НастройкиКомпоновки = КомпоновщикНастроек.ПолучитьНастройки();

    КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;
    МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных, НастройкиКомпоновки, ДанныеРасшифровки);

    ПроцессорКомпоновки = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
    ПроцессорКомпоновки.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновки,, ДанныеРасшифровки);

    ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьДокумент(ДокументРезультат);
    ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновки);

    Если ДокументРезультат.ФиксацияСверху Тогда
        ДокументРезультат.ПовторятьПриПечатиСтроки = ДокументРезультат.Область(1,, ДокументРезультат.ФиксацияСверху);
    КонецЕсли;

КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: _____________________СПАСИБО !!!! ______________________